# How to setup a analytics system using multiple apps?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql

I have a front-end application runs on Rails 4 + Postgres. Let's call it `FRONT_APP`.
I have an application for statistics run Rails 4 + Mongodb. Let's call it `STATISTICS_APP`.

In my `FRONT_APP`, I use this skeleton XHR query with this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/hits",
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: { user_data: "Value", token: "TokenString"}
})
```

I'm sending a `POST` request to `STATISTICS_APP` and creating a `Hit` instance which has proper data. By this way I will collect millions of rows data at my Mongodb.

And in a worker of my `STATISTICS_APP`, I will evaluate all data and with a direct connection to my production Postgres db, I will update respective tables.

As a result, I will show statistics information via my Postgres db.

Do you think that it's a convenient way to do this job?

Or do you have a better workflow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is standard [`analytics` stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics) - send a request to another system, which initiates a request on the analytics server (hence recording the request as a `hit` or similar)

---

Although your structure is correct (send requests asynchronously to the other app), I would stay clear of ajax -- a better way will be to request a resource from the other server (typically a [1px gif like Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#howAnalyticsGetsData)):

> **How the Tracking Code Works**
>
> In general, the Google Analytics Tracking Code (GATC) retrieves web
>   page data as follows:
>
> A browser requests a web page that contains the tracking code. A
>   JavaScript Array named _gaq is created and tracking commands are
>   pushed onto the array. A  element is created and enabled for
>   asynchronous loading (loading in the background). The ga.js tracking
>   code is fetched, with the appropriate protocol automatically detected.
>   Once the code is fetched and loaded, the commands on the _gaq array
>   are executed and the array is transformed into a tracking object.
>   Subsequent tracking calls are made directly to Google Analytics. Loads
>   the script element to the DOM. After the tracking code collects data,
>   the GIF request is sent to the Analytics database for logging and
>   post-processing.

---

We've done something similar, but since our app is in development still, we're actually still using an `xmlhttprequest` (`ajax` in disguise):

```
//v0.0.230
//authenticates with server
(function(token) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://*******.herokuapp.com/data",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    xmlhttp.send();
})(tracker);
```

---

**Data**

In terms of storing data, we actually capture all naked data in Redis & then store in Postgres (heroku) afterwards

We've not developed for long with it, but as for data retention, you should definitely look at storing "short term" data & "long term" data

Hope this gives some direction?

Comment: It's a great answer Rich, thank you! Do you know any good resources to understand better Google style analytic collecting?

Comment: The best thing is to just look at what analytics companies have already created -- these guys all use the same technology, so it will be best to see how they manage massive data flows etc :)

Comment: Actually, I think I'm looking for an existing code example or something like that :) Have you found any good blog posts or Github repos during your project?

Comment: Hmmmm I think I did, but I forgot where they were. I like to work by getting a concept & working around that. Let me see if I can find any for you